# opposite of list-ref? (Racket)

Tags: list, racket, abstract, higher-order-functions

Is there anything which acts as the opposite of list-ref, where instead of selecting certain values to add to a list, it'll take values away from a list?

I basically want to do the following

```
 (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7) (list 3 6 7) -> (list 1 2 4 5)
```

Where the values in list two get deleted from list one. (preferred)

Since I will always start with a list that goes from 1 to n,
the second list could also represent the location/position where a number on list 1 should be deleted. (less preferred)

I'm trying to create a code which will manipulate other functions to come up with these lists, so please be clear where each list is 'mentioned' in the code, as I sometimes get confused if people use x y and z and so forth with multiple lambda, local definitions, etc.

---

I have something here which does the opposite of what I want and I've been trying to alter it so instead of outputting the elements of x that are on y, it gives the elements of x which are NOT on y.

```
(define (selection x y)
  (filter  (lambda (e2)
            (ormap (lambda (e1) (equal? e1 e2))
                   y))
          x))
```

example:

```
        (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
         (list 2 4 6 8 10))
    ->  (list 2 4 6 8 10))
```

Anybody have any ideas on how to change the output to what I need?

Comment: What? `list-ref` hasn't much to do with "selecting certain values to add to a list".

Comment: My description doesn't make much sense, I was just trying to say I wanted to do the inverse of it in some sense.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using `list`s as sets. You could instead use Racket `set`s, and use the [`set-subtract`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-subtract%29%29) function:

```
#lang racket

(set-subtract (set 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
              (set 3 6 7))
;; => (set 1 2 4 5)
```

Comment: I haven't learnt about sets yet. Do you have any way to do this using abstraction/higher order function?

Answer (score 2):

`remove` will do the trick I guess.

```
> (remove* (list 1 2) (list 1 2 3 2 4 5 2))
'(3 4 5)
```

You can read the [doc here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=remv#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29).

Comment: remove* may work, but the problem is it isn't defined at the language level I'm stuck using. Do you know how to define using recursion or abstraction at all?

Comment: Yes, and it shouldn't be very hard. Give it a try and comeback with some code you've written. A hint: use `cons` when *building* the resulting list. You'll have to check every item of the first list for every one of the second. Everytime you've traveled through the first list, use `cdr` to shorten it for next recursive call. .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple recursive function that achieves what you want:

```lisp
(define remove-list-from-list (lambda (list remlist)
    (cond
        [(null? list) '()]
        [(member (car list) remlist) (remove-list-from-list (cdr list) remlist)]
        [else (cons (car list) (remove-list-from-list (cdr list) remlist))])))
```

Now you can use it like so:

```lisp
> (remove-list-from-list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7) (list 3 6 7))
'(1 2 4 5)
```